# Why is the analytic continuation of this local holomorphic function one-to-one?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-manifolds

In Nakahara's GTaP chapter 8.1, he introduces the lattice $L(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ generated by two complex numbers $\omega_i$ (where $\text{Im}(\omega_1/\omega_2)>0$). Then he defines a complex structure on $T^2$ by introducing the equivalence relation of complex numbers $z_1\sim z_2$ iff $z_1=z_2+n\omega_1+m\omega_2$ with $m,n\in\mathbb Z$, so $\mathbb C/L(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ is $T^2$ as a complex manifold.

Then he examines the complex structures of two different pairs of complex numbers $(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ and $(\tilde\omega_1,\tilde\omega_2)$:

> Assume that there exists a one-to-one holomorphic map $h$ of $\mathbb C/L(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ onto $\mathbb C/L(\tilde\omega_1,\tilde\omega_2)$ where $\text{Im}(\omega_1/\omega_2)>0$, $\text{Im}(\tilde\omega_1/\tilde\omega_2)>0$. Let $p:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C/L(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ and $\tilde p:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C/L(\tilde\omega_1,\tilde\omega_2)$ be the natural projections. [...] Choose the origin $0$ and define $h_*(0)$ to be a point such that $\tilde p\circ h_*(0)=h\circ p(0)$.
>
> Then by analytic continuation from the origin, we obtain a one-to-one holomorphic map $h_*$ of $\mathbb C$ onto itself satifying $\tilde p\circ h_*(0)=h\circ p(0)$.

Why do we know that $h_*$ is one-to-one $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$? Why aren't there singularities? Why is $h_*$ surjective onto $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Do you know some topology? Then note that $h_{\ast}$ is a morphism of coverings.

Comment: @DanielFischer I suppose you're saying that $\mathbb C$ is a covering of $\mathbb C/L(\omega_1,\omega_2)$. The analytic continuation of $h_*$ is holomorphic, so it is also continuous and thus it is a homeomorphism. But why does that tell me that there cannot be any singularities, and that it must be surjective onto $\mathbb C$?

Comment: $p$ and $\tilde{p}$ are covering maps. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is simply connected, $h$ has exactly one lift for every point above $h(p(0))$. That gives you a continuous function $h_{\ast}$ with $\tilde{p}\circ h_{\ast} = h\circ p$. And we can also lift $h^{-1}$, then $(h^{-1})_{\ast} \circ h_{\ast}$ and $h_{\ast} \circ (h^{-1})_{\ast}$ are lifts of the respective identities on the tori with a fixed point, hence the identity on $\mathbb{C}$. So $h_{\ast}$ is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ with itself. Since the projections are locally biholomorphic, $h_{\ast}$ holomorphic.

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay so $h_*$ is holomorphic. Why is it bijective? Also, which theorem implies your first statement? (*...has exactly one lift...*)